# Find last values by condition

Tags: r, subset, tail

I have a very large data frame that I need to subset by last values.  I know that the `data.table` library includes the `last()` function which returns the last value of an array, but what I need is to subset `foo` by the last value in `id` for every separate value in `track`.  Values in `id` are consecutive integers, but the last values will be different for every `track`.

```
> head(foo)
  track id  coords.x coords.y
1     0  0 -79.90732 43.26133
2     0  1 -79.90733 43.26124
3     0  2 -79.90733 43.26124
4     0  3 -79.90733 43.26124
5     0  4 -79.90725 43.26121
6     0  5 -79.90725 43.26121
```

The output would look something like this.

```
   track  id  coords.x coords.y
1     0   57  -79.90756 43.26123
2     1   98  -79.90777 43.26231
3     2   61  -79.90716 43.26200
```

... and so on

How would one apply the `last()` function (or another function like `tail()`) to produce this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'track' get the last row with `tail`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, tail(.SD, 1), by = track]
```

---

As the also mentioned another logic with 'id' about the consecutive numbers, we can also create a logical index using `diff`, get the row index (`.I`) and subset the rows.

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[c(FALSE, diff(id) ! = 1)], by = track]$V1]
```

---

Or we can do this using `base R` itself

```
df1[!duplicated(df1$track, fromLast=TRUE),]
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(track) %>%
    slice(n())
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try with `dplyr`, grouping by `track` and selecting only the last row of every group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(track) %>%
   filter(row_number() == n())
```